# Add Custom Currency With Java In Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i am developing an android application for the business in country and we are not using us dollars, and on every tutorials that am passing through are teaching me how to make the us dollar currency. So how can i use the following code to form my custom currency which is used by my community. `Locale locale = new Locale("en","US");`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale inLocale)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale)).

*Examples*

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US).format(12345.6789));      // dollar
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CANADA).format(12345.6789));  // dollar
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK).format(12345.6789));      // pound
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.GERMANY).format(12345.6789)); // euro
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE).format(12345.6789));  // euro
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.ITALY).format(12345.6789));   // euro
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("se-SE"/*Sweden*/)).format(12345.6789));
```

*Output*

```
$12,345.68
$12,345.68
£12,345.68
12.345,68 €
12 345,68 €
12.345,68 €
12 345,68 kr
```